# Trying to hide sheets for everyone except admins

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to hide sheets from all viewers with a code without hiding it with the default options, i've tried the following code but it's not working. Does anyone know a solution?

```
function onOpen() {
  var admin = ['owner@gmail.com']

   if (admin.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2').showSheet()
   }
    else {SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Certs').hideSheet()
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the name of the sheet you're manipulating? Or is it two different sheets?

Separately, if there's only one admin, your `indexOf` is doing a lot of work compared to something like `if (Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() == admin`

Comment: Yes, I have 2 sheets i want to hide.

Answer (score 1):

### Your approach is problematic if an admin and non-admin user have the spreadsheet open at the same time

A Google Spreadsheet is not a Schrödinger's cat, it's sheets cannot be shown and hidden at the same time.

I suggest you a different approach:

- Create a second spreadsheet that includes only the sheets that the non-admins are allowed to see.
- You can sync the `admin` and `non-admin` spreadsheets, so that the non-hidden sheets would contain the same information in both.